# is installing local node necessary to create wallet on test/main net?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, wavesplatform

i want to be able to create wallets on wave blockchain using their api

according to this

https://nodes-testnet.wavesnodes.com/api-docs/index.html#/addresses/createWalletAddress

i need to send `API key` in my request header .... i look into how can i obtain this api key and in the doc here are the steps

> Set API Key
>
> To set API key, you need to generate API key hash and then use it in
> your node configuration.
>
> Create unique string value that you will use as API key.
>
> Go to Swagger web interface.
>
> Open the /utils/hash/secure (opens new window)API method and input
> your unique string in the message field.
>
> Click Execute to get the hashed API key.
>
> Use the hashed API key as the value of the api-key-hash parameter in
> your node configuration file.
>
> Restart your node.

it says

> Use the hashed API key as the value of the api-key-hash parameter in
> your node configuration file.

im very confused ... i thought using testnet means that i dont have to install a local node
maybe im wrong ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@waves/waves-api

you need to creaate a seed pharase , and using the seed you can create address/public & private keys ... here is a shortcut to create all

```
const Waves = WavesAPI.create(WavesAPI.TESTNET_CONFIG);
const seed = Waves.Seed.create();
console.log(seed);
```